# Airflow: Package installation to Execute RScripts in Airflow

Tags: r, airflow, airflow-2.x

**Requirement**: To execute RScripts via Airflow

**Airflow Version** : 2.3.3 in EKS

Tried installing `python3 -m pip install rpy2` via DockerFile, Below is the error description

**Error** :

```
Collecting rpy2
#5 90.44   Downloading rpy2-3.5.6.tar.gz (211 kB)
#5 91.03   Installing build dependencies: started
#5 107.7   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#5 107.7   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#5 108.3   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
#5 108.3   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#5 108.3
#5 108.3   × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
#5 108.3   │ exit code: 1
#5 108.3   ╰─> [6 lines of output]
#5 108.3       Unable to determine R home: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'R'
#5 108.3       cffi mode is CFFI_MODE.ANY
#5 108.3       Looking for R home with: R RHOME
#5 108.3       Unable to determine R home: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'R'
#5 108.3       R home found: None
#5 108.3       Error: rpy2 in API mode cannot be built without R in the PATH or R_HOME defined. Correct this or force ABI mode-only by defining the environment variable RPY2_CFFI_MODE=ABI
#5 108.3       [end of output]
#5 108.3
#5 108.3   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#5 108.3 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#5 108.3
#5 108.3 × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
#5 108.3 │ exit code: 1
#5 108.3 ╰─> See above for output.
#5 108.3
#5 108.3 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
------
```

Comment: Why you need r2py ? You can run the R code directly with a Bash airflow operator.

Comment: @polkas I tried running in bashoperator as below but got an error ```bash_task2 = BashOperator (task_id='bash_task2', bash_command="Rscript /opt/airflow/dags/R_script.R")```

Comment: Error is ```bash: line 1: Rscript: command not found
INFO - Command exited with return code 127```

Comment: Please check out if R is installed on your container, e.g. “which R” and “which Rscript” commands.  Useful References  https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/218012917-How-to-run-R-scripts-from-the-command-line and https://lcalcagni.medium.com/running-r-scripts-in-airflow-using-airflow-bashoperators-6d827f5da5b1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with the below inclusion in the DockerFile

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base r-base-core && \
    rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN python3 -m pip install rpy2
```